# Gupshup proxy bot doesn't work on MS Team

Tags: bots, microsoft-teams, gupshup

I am currently trying to create a bot for several platform : Slack, MS Team and Cisco Spark.
I did some test with gupshup, using their bot : gupshup proxy bot, and it works well on Slack and Spark. But neither my bots nor gupshup proxy bot reply on MS Team.
My admin already enable sideloading app.

Do you have the same issues ?

Comment: How are you talking to the bot? 1:1 or in a channel? 

When you click on [this](https://teams.microsoft.com/l/chat/0/0?users=28:bdc707d5-48e0-48f8-bbe7-6131e0565a4c) you should a new chat with one of my sample bots. Does that work?

Comment: 1:1. I tested with a bot in their "suggested" list and it works. Your bot works too. That's why I doesn't understand :/ I added gupshup bot with the same way that I add your bot. Their is the official link : https://www.gupshup.io/developer/demobots

Comment: Gupshup support answered me. They have issues and they are correcting it. I have to wait. I will tell you when it is corrected.

Answer (score 1):

There is some configuration issue with the proxy bot. We at Gupshup are getting it fixed and it should start working for everyone soon.

Although as a workaround please try publishing your bot on MS teams for testing. This [guide's](https://www.gupshup.io/developer/docs/bot-platform/guide/build-deploy-test-bots-on-microsoftteams)  **publish** section explains the steps which you need to follow.

PS: I work for Gupshup.

Comment: It looks like it is still not working for me :/ Should I contact your support again ?

Comment: can you tell me the bot names that are not working on proxy bot on MS teams?

Comment: Finally I will not deploy on MS Team. And it is your proxy bot gupshup that isn't working on MS Team.